# How to git undo merge for file

Tags: git, git-merge

in git. 
I'm looking for the best aproach to merge master into feature branch, yet, to skip on files [path_to_file_a]/a and [path_to_file_b]/b

ideas ?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
git log
# "q" to quit
# note the first commit hash (for HEAD commit), let's call it <hash>
git merge master
git checkout <hash> [path_to_file_a]/a
git checkout <hash> [path_to_file_b]/b
```

To commit the result:

```
git commit -a
```

Comment: Thx. and how should I "force" git to merge master into branch with NO conflict resolution ??

Comment: If I understand, you want to auto-resolve any conflicts when merging master into your feature branch non-interactively (without user intervention). Presumably for each file containing any conflict(s), you want to take the version of the file from master (except for `a` and `b`, which we've already covered). In that case you'd alter the merge command to `git merge -X theirs master` but otherwise do the same steps from my answer.